# Converting a Java Keystore into PEM Format

Tags: java, encryption, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to convert from a Java keystore file into a PEM file using `keytool` and `openssl` applications. However, I could not find an ideal way to do the conversion. Any thoughts?

Instead of converting the keystore directly into `PEM`, I tried to create a `PKCS12` file first and then convert it into a relevant PEM file and Keystore. However, I could not establish a connection using them.

(Note that I need a PEM file and a Keystore file to implement a secured connection. There is no restriction like "Start from a java keystore file". So starting from other formats is acceptable in my case)

But a direct conversion method from `jks` to `pem` is preferable.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

### It's pretty straightforward, using jdk6 at least...

```
bash$ keytool -keystore foo.jks -genkeypair -alias foo \
        -dname 'CN=foo.example.com,L=Melbourne,ST=Victoria,C=AU'
Enter keystore password:  
Re-enter new password: 
Enter key password for 
        (RETURN if same as keystore password):  
bash$ keytool -keystore foo.jks -exportcert -alias foo | \
       openssl x509 -inform der -text
Enter keystore password:  asdasd
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1237334757 (0x49c03ae5)
        Signature Algorithm: dsaWithSHA1
        Issuer: C=AU, ST=Victoria, L=Melbourne, CN=foo.example.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 18 00:05:57 2009 GMT
            Not After : Jun 16 00:05:57 2009 GMT
        Subject: C=AU, ST=Victoria, L=Melbourne, CN=foo.example.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: dsaEncryption
            DSA Public Key:
                pub: 
                    00:e2:66:5c:e0:2e:da:e0:6b:a6:aa:97:64:59:14:
                    7e:a6:2e:5a:45:f9:2f:b5:2d:f4:34:27:e6:53:c7:
 

bash$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore foo.jks \
       -destkeystore foo.p12 \
       -srcstoretype jks \
       -deststoretype pkcs12
Enter destination keystore password:  
Re-enter new password: 
Enter source keystore password:  
Entry for alias foo successfully imported.
Import command completed:  1 entries successfully imported, 0 entries failed or cancelled

bash$ openssl pkcs12 -in foo.p12 -out foo.pem
Enter Import Password:
MAC verified OK
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:

bash$ openssl x509 -text -in foo.pem
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1237334757 (0x49c03ae5)
        Signature Algorithm: dsaWithSHA1
        Issuer: C=AU, ST=Victoria, L=Melbourne, CN=foo.example.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 18 00:05:57 2009 GMT
            Not After : Jun 16 00:05:57 2009 GMT
        Subject: C=AU, ST=Victoria, L=Melbourne, CN=foo.example.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: dsaEncryption
            DSA Public Key:
                pub: 
                    00:e2:66:5c:e0:2e:da:e0:6b:a6:aa:97:64:59:14:
                    7e:a6:2e:5a:45:f9:2f:b5:2d:f4:34:27:e6:53:c7:
 

bash$ openssl dsa -text -in foo.pem
read DSA key
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Private-Key: (1024 bit)
priv:
    00:8f:b1:af:55:63:92:7c:d2:0f:e6:f3:a2:f5:ff:
    1a:7a:fe:8c:39:dd
pub: 
    00:e2:66:5c:e0:2e:da:e0:6b:a6:aa:97:64:59:14:
    7e:a6:2e:5a:45:f9:2f:b5:2d:f4:34:27:e6:53:c7:
```

You end up with:

- foo.jks - keystore in java format.
- foo.p12 - keystore in PKCS#12 format.
- foo.pem - all keys and certs from keystore, in PEM format.

(This last file can be split up into keys and certificates if you like.)

---

#### Command summary - to create JKS keystore:

```
keytool -keystore foo.jks -genkeypair -alias foo \
    -dname 'CN=foo.example.com,L=Melbourne,ST=Victoria,C=AU'
```

#### Command summary - to convert JKS keystore into PKCS#12 keystore, then into PEM file:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore foo.jks \
   -destkeystore foo.p12 \
   -srcstoretype jks \
   -deststoretype pkcs12

openssl pkcs12 -in foo.p12 -out foo.pem
```

if you have more than one certificate in your JKS keystore, and you want to only export the certificate and key associated with one of the aliases, you can use the following variation:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore foo.jks \
   -destkeystore foo.p12 \
   -srcalias foo \
   -srcstoretype jks \
   -deststoretype pkcs12

openssl pkcs12 -in foo.p12 -out foo.pem
```

#### Command summary - to compare JKS keystore to PEM file:

```
keytool -keystore foo.jks -exportcert -alias foo | \
   openssl x509 -inform der -text

openssl x509 -text -in foo.pem

openssl dsa -text -in foo.pem
```

Comment: Trusted certificates are not supported in this method: this is a restriction of the PKS12 format I believe see: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#InstallProbs
(section on java.security.KeyStoreException: TrustedCertEntry not supported)

Comment: @andygavin: Indeed; this is true. While the PKCS format can hold arbitrarily many certificates, it does not have a field to indicate whether the certificate is trusted or not. However, the question was about how to end up with a PEM (PKCS#7) file, which also doesn't have this trust information, so it's not an issue of the process...

Comment: I have an older JKS file. I could not export using the method above. I finally was able to do it by setting keytool arg '-destkeypass' to a dummy value. 'keytool' even prompts a warning saying it is ignoring destkeypass value? No other technique would work. Using the prompts did not work, only works from the command line argument. Must be a bug in the PKCS12 export, can anyone comment?

Comment: "openssl pkcs12 -in foo.p12 -out foo.pem" throws the following error
Enter Import Password:
MAC verified OK
Error outputting keys and certificates
139848775526048:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:539:
139848775526048:error:23077074:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_pbe_crypt:pkcs12 cipherfinal error:p12_decr.c:104:
139848775526048:error:2306A075:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_item_decrypt_d2i:pkcs12 pbe crypt error:p12_decr.c:130. What is the solution for this?

Comment: a warning for other people, the keytool command takes a while to complete for some reason, I had to wait 30 seconds until the export was done

Comment: @UdaraS.SLiyanage: look at Casey's answer for the solution

Comment: I got errors (keytool error: java.io.IOException: DER input, Integer tag error) until I deleted the destination keystore file before running the command. Make sure that the destination keystore file does not exist before running the command.

Comment: If you're using git-bash on windows, you may want to prefix `openssl ...` with `winpty openssl ...`

Answer (score 31):

I kept getting errors from `openssl` when using StoBor's command:

```
MAC verified OK
Error outputting keys and certificates
139940235364168:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:535:
139940235364168:error:23077074:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_pbe_crypt:pkcs12 cipherfinal error:p12_decr.c:97:
139940235364168:error:2306A075:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_item_decrypt_d2i:pkcs12 pbe crypt error:p12_decr.c:123:
```

For some reason, only this style of command would work for my JKS file

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore foo.jks \
   -destkeystore foo.p12 \
   -srcstoretype jks \
   -srcalias mykey \
   -deststoretype pkcs12 \
   -destkeypass DUMMY123
```

The key was setting `destkeypass`, the value of the argument did not matter.

Comment: The reasoning can be found here: http://www.herongyang.com/PKI/Intermediate-CA-OpenSSL-pkcs12-Decrypt-Error.html The destkeypass DOES matter btw

Comment: I upvoted this comment but it deserves it's own post. It was tough to find here.

Answer (score 21):

Direct conversion from jks to pem file using the keytool

```
keytool -exportcert -alias selfsigned -keypass password -keystore test-user.jks -rfc -file test-user.pem
```

Comment: Yep, that exports the certificate. However, it does not export the key information...

Comment: This is the exact simple answer to what I was searching on dozens of `keytool` and `jboss` doc pages without success. Thanks!

Comment: THIS DOES NOT EXPORT PRIVATE KEY INFORMATION

Comment: This exports public key certificate

Comment: I tried running this command. It requires password,Enter keystore password:
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect.

I have used password as(password) but it was throwing same error

Comment: where it will save the `pem` file?

Comment: This exports  public.pem certificate. How to find private.pem

Answer (score 15):

The `keytool` command will not allow you to export the private key from a key store. You have to write some Java code to do this. Open the key store, get the key you need, and save it to a file in PKCS #8 format. Save the associated certificate too.

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
/* Load the key store. */
...
char[] password = ...;
/* Save the private key. */
FileOutputStream kos = new FileOutputStream("tmpkey.der");
Key pvt = ks.getKey("your_alias", password);
kos.write(pvt.getEncoded());
kos.flush();
kos.close();
/* Save the certificate. */
FileOutputStream cos = new FileOutputStream("tmpcert.der");
Certificate pub = ks.getCertificate("your_alias");
cos.write(pub.getEncoded());
cos.flush();
cos.close();
```

Use OpenSSL utilities to convert these files (which are in binary format) to PEM format.

```
openssl pkcs8 -inform der -nocrypt < tmpkey.der > tmpkey.pem
openssl x509 -inform der < tmpcert.der > tmpcert.pem
```

Comment: Thanks erickson.. The conclusion is "We can't perform a direct conversion from JKS to PEM by just using keytool and openssl utilities". Am I correct?

Comment: You only __need__ to write code up to Java 1.4 - from Java 5 onwards, keytool and openssl can be combined to perform a two stage conversion from JKS ->  PKCS#12 -> PEM. However, writing your own key tool is the only way to perform __DIRECT CONVERSION__ from JKS -> PEM.

Comment: I think it's from JDK 6 onward. But yes, a PKCS #12 import is now supported.

Answer (score 15):

Simplified instructions to converts a JKS file to PEM and KEY format (.crt & .key):

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore <Source-Java-Key-Store-File> -destkeystore <Destination-Pkcs12-File> -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12 -destkeypass <Destination-Key-Password>

openssl pkcs12 -in <Destination-Pkcs12-File> -out <Destination-Pem-File>

openssl x509 -outform der -in <Destination-Pem-File> -out <Destination-Crt-File>

openssl rsa -in <Destination-Pem-File> -out <Destination-Key-File>
```

Answer (score 6):

Converting a JKS KeyStore to a single PEM file can easily be accomplished using the following command:

```
keytool -list -rfc -keystore "myKeystore.jks" | sed -e "/-*BEGIN [A-Z]*-*/,/-*END [A-Z]-*/!d" >> "myKeystore.pem"
```

Explanation:

1. `keytool -list -rfc -keystore "myKeystore.jks"` lists everything in the 'myKeyStore.jks' KeyStore in PEM format. However, it also prints extra information.
2. `| sed -e "/-*BEGIN [A-Z]*-*/,/-*END [A-Z]-*/!d"` filters out everything we don't need. We are left with only the PEMs of everything in the KeyStore.
3. `>> "myKeystore.pem"` write the PEMs to the file 'myKeyStore.pem'.

Comment: bash: !d": event not found

Comment: @user3217883 You could try something like `sed "s/^\-*BEGIN [A-Z]*\-*$//g;s/^\-*END [A-Z]*\-*$//g"` instead (with gnu sed) but i'm not sure that's enough if there are more than one cert in your keystore

Comment: if you're getting `bash: !d": event not found` : for bash an exclamation mark is a short key to use a command.  To use this answer you need to use apostrophes in place of the quotes for the option used as -e for sed `keytool -list -rfc -keystore "myKeystore.jks" | sed -e '/-*BEGIN [A-Z]*-*/,/-*END [A-Z]-*/!d' >> "myKeystore.pem"`

Comment: Unfortunately, this only exports the certificate, not the private key

Comment: @user3217883 Try single quotes instead of double quotes, e.g., `...  | sed -e "/-*BEGIN [A-Z]*-*/,/-*END [A-Z]-*/!d" >> ...`

Answer (score 4):

First dump the keystore from JKS to PKCS12

1.
 **keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -destkeystore intermediate.p12 -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12**

Dump the new pkcs12 file into pem

2. **openssl pkcs12 -in intermediate.p12 -nodes -out intermediate.rsa.pem**

You should have both the cert and private key in pem format. Split them up.
Put the part between “BEGIN CERTIFICATE” and “END CERTIFICATE” into cert.x509.pem
Put the part between “BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY” and “END RSA PRIVATE KEY” into private.rsa.pem
Convert the private key into pk8 format as expected by signapk

3.
**openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -outform DER -in private.rsa.pem -inform PEM -out private.pk8 -nocrypt**

Comment: In OpenSSL versions 1.0.0 (released 2010) and up, `openssl pkcs12` should already output the privatekey in PKCS8 format -- but PEM, so if you need DER you do need either the specific conversion by `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -outform der` or the generic one for a single isolated PEM block (only) `openssl base64 -d`

Answer (score 4):

Suppose your keystore file is abcd.jks and its present at C:\Data,

try this in cmd window, at the location where the file is present:

```
keytool -export -rfc -keystore C:\Data\abcd.jks -alias abcd -file C:\Data\abcd.pem
```

Give password next, when prompted, and you will get the converted format at the location specified

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't have openssl installed and you are looking for a quick solution, there is software called [portcle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) which is very useful and small to download.

The disadvantage is that there is no command line as far as I know.
But from the GUI, it is pretty straight forward to export a PEM private key:

1. Open you JKS key store
2. Right click over your private key entry and select export
3. Select Private Key and certificates and PEM format

   [image: Export PEM private key from JKS with Portcle]

Answer (score 3):

open your terminal and going to jks file location
and write this >>>>
keytool -export -rfc -alias key0 -file android_certificate.pem -keystore androidkey.jks

Answer (score 1):

Well, [OpenSSL should do it handily](http://gagravarr.org/writing/openssl-certs/general.shtml) from a #12 file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in pkcs-12-certificate-file -out pem-certificate-file
openssl pkcs12 -in pkcs-12-certificate-and-key-file -out pem-certificate-and-key-file
```

Maybe more details on what the error/failure is?

Answer (score 1):

Try Keystore Explorer http://keystore-explorer.org/

KeyStore Explorer is an open source GUI replacement for the Java command-line utilities keytool and jarsigner. It does openssl/pkcs12 as well.

Answer (score 1):

first create keystore file as

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin>**keytool -keystore androidkey.jks -genkeypair -alias androidkey**

Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
What is your first and last name?
  Unknown:  **FirstName LastName**
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  Unknown:  **Mobile Development**
What is the name of your organization?
  Unknown:  **your company name**
What is the name of your City or Locality?
What is the name of your State or Province?

What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  Unknown:  IN   //press enter

> Now it will ask to confirm

Is CN=FirstName LastName, OU=Mobile Development, O=your company name, L=CityName, ST=StateName, C=IN correct?
  [no]:  **yes**

Enter key password for 
        (RETURN if same as keystore password):  press enter if you want same password

> key has been generated, now you can simply get pem file using following command

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin>**keytool -export -rfc -alias androidkey -file android_certificate.pem -keystore androidkey.jks**
Enter keystore password:
Certificate stored in file

Comment: This doesn't add anything useful to [the 2011 answer by sanghaviss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6076689/2868801) and it outputs only the cert not the private key

Answer (score 0):

I just leave following two commands here that does the job

```
# openssl pkcs12 -info -nodes -in /srv/apache-tomcat-8.5.72/conf/cert.jks -nokeys 2>&1| sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > server.crt
Enter Import Password:
# openssl pkcs12 -info -nodes -in /srv/apache-tomcat-8.5.72/conf/cert.jks -nocerts 2>&1| sed -ne '/-BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-/,/-END PRIVATE KEY-/p' > server.key
Enter Import Password:
```

Answer (score 0):

keytool -exportcert -alias selfsigned -keypass **password** -keystore **key-store.jks** -rfc -file test-user.pem

The command will prompt to enter keyStore password - Enter the keystore password

password - The key password.
key-store - The keystore file (jks or keystore)

it will be easy when you have **key** and **keystore** passwords the same.

Answer (score -2):

> Converting a Java Keystore into PEM Format

The most precise answer of all must be that this is NOT possible.

A Java keystore is merely a storage facility for cryptographic keys **and** certificates while PEM is a file format for X.509 certificates only.

Comment: This is quite wrong. PEM files are widely used for certificates, CRLs, (PKCS10) CSRs, and private keys, and less widely for PKCS7/CMS messages (including p7b/p7c cert and/or CRL bundles), bare public keys, parameters, and more rarely things like OpenSSL saved-session blocks and OCSP messages. For the _officially standard_ ones see [RFC7468](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7468).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - True, that PEM is not only about X.509 certificates. However my point has been that you can store *anything* within a Java Keystore as long as it complies with the (empty) interface of  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.Entry.html - while PEM appears to be bound to some Crypto standards (and not to an arbitrary base64 encoding).

Comment: All JCA APIs including KeyStore are (intentionally) very broad, but actual implementations behind those APIs need not be. For important examples JKS and PKCS12 support only certificate types for which a certificatefactory exists, and the only certificatefactory that exists is X.509. PEM (RFC1421) 'printable encoding' can be applied to any binary data, although it is mostly used for ASN.1 data (mostly DER, some BER e.g. PKCS7/CMS) which is still a very wide set. (The very similar MIME base64 encoding, defined almost simultaneously, is used for all kinds of data.)