# How can I move my SSL cert from Tomcat to Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, openssl, keystore

I am moving my site from a tomcat only instance to an apache httd/ apache tomcat setup.  I'm trying to set up the ssl with mod_ssl on apache httpd.  But I don't know how to convert my tomcat keystoreFile/keystorePass to the apache httpd SSLCertificateFile/SSLCertificateKeyFile format.  I am pouring over the openssl man pages with no luck.  I am running the site on Fedora 13.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Java `keytool -importkeystore` utility to convert the "JKS" format key store file to a standard "PKCS #12" format. Then use OpenSSL to convert the PKCS #12 file to whatever format you require. You can see full details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652916/converting-a-java-keystore-into-pem-format/656559#656559) to a duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you.  I did not realize that was the format I was looking for.  I also found this link a minute ago that helped also. http://www.zimbra.com/forums/administrators/9832-exporting-private-key-keystore-use-postfix-apache.html

Comment: Yes, that article that you linked to provides code that's a lot like what [I gave in *my* answer to the duplicate question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652916/converting-a-java-keystore-into-pem-format/653083#653083) Before Java 6, you couldn't convert key store formats, and had to write your own code (or download a library like your article shows). Now, it's a built-in function of `keytool`.