# How to create pem file using JKS file

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, pem

I want to create two `.pem` files one for `client` and other for `server`, Based on my understanding `client pem file` will have `servers public key + clients private key` and `server pem file` will have `client public key + servers private key`. I have created `jks` file from http://yellowcat1.free.fr/keytool_iui.html

What are the steps to follow to achive required `pem files` and those `.pem` file should be `password enabled`.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [converting-a-java-keystore-into-pem-format][1]. Refer this post.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652916/converting-a-java-keystore-into-pem-format

Comment: But it does not talk about client and server .pem files which is where I am confused.

Comment: There is no difference except that a client keystore may or may not contain a private key. All the steps are the same.