# CURL to pass SSL certifcate and password

Tags: java, unix, curl, curly-braces

I need to specify a certificate with CURL i tried with --cert option it is not working.

Could you please let me know to specify the keystore and passpharse while invoking with curl?

Answer (score 42):

Should be:

```
curl --cert certificate_file.pem:password https://www.example.com/some_protected_page
```

Comment: Can i specify a JKS file with this option?

Comment: You can't use cURL with a **Java** KeyStore. Here is a good SO Answer that details converting it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/652916/971423

Answer (score 9):

I went through this when trying to get a clientcert and private key out of a keystore.

The link above posted by welsh was great, but there was an extra step on my redhat distribution.  If curl is built with NSS  ( run `curl --version` to see if you see NSS listed)  then you need to import the keys into an NSS keystore.  I went through a bunch of convoluted steps, so this may not be the cleanest way, but it got things working

So export the keys into .p12

> ```
> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore $jksfile -destkeystore $p12file \
>         -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 \
>         -srcstorepass $jkspassword -deststorepass $p12password  
>         -srcalias $myalias -destalias $myalias \
>         -srckeypass $keypass -destkeypass $keypass -noprompt
> ```

And generate the pem file that holds only the key

> ```
>  echo making ${fileroot}.key.pem
>  openssl pkcs12 -in $p12 -out ${fileroot}.key.pem  \
>          -passin pass:$p12password  \
>          -passout pass:$p12password  -nocerts
> ```

- Make an empty keystore:

> ```
> mkdir ~/nss
> chmod 700 ~/nss
> certutil -N -d ~/nss
> ```

- Import the keys into the keystore

> ```
> pks12util -i <mykeys>.p12 -d ~/nss -W <password for cert >
> ```

Now curl should work.

> ```
> curl --insecure --cert <client cert alias>:<password for cert> \
>      --key ${fileroot}.key.pem  <URL>
> ```

As I mentioned, there may be other ways to do this, but at least this was repeatable for me.  If curl is compiled with NSS support, I was not able to get it to pull the client cert from a file.

Comment: The pks12util command doesn't exist and should be pk12util.

I also had to set the nss location through: `export SSL_DIR=~/nss`

Answer (score 5):

Addition to previous answer make sure that your curl installation supports https.

You can use `curl --version` to get information about supported protocols.

If your curl supports https follow the previous answer.

> curl --cert certificate_path:password https://www.example.com

If it does not support https, you need to install a cURL version that supports https.