# Logstash TLS Cert JKS to PKCS8 Invalid Key Error

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch, logstash, tls1.2

I'm trying to convert a JKS cert to PKCS8 for Logstash v5.1.
I found an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/656559

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore foo.jks -destkeystore foo.p12 / 
  -srcstoretype jks   -deststoretype pkcs12
openssl pkcs12 -in foo.p12 -out foo.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in foo.p12 -nocerts -out key.pem
openssl pkcs8 -in key.pem -topk8 -out p8key.pem
```

But it produces the following error when attempting to run logstash:

```
ERROR logstash.inputs.beats - Looks like you either have an invalid key or your private key was not in PKCS8 format.
{:exception=>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File does not contain valid private key: /ELK/logstash/SSL/p8key.pem}
```

I also tried to convert to pkcs8 with the `-nocrypt` flag, and receive this error:

```
ERROR org.logstash.beats.BeatsHandler - Exception: not an SSL/TLS record
```

Answer (score 2):

The cause of this error:

```
ERROR logstash.inputs.beats - Looks like you either have an invalid key or your private key was not in PKCS8 format.
{:exception=>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File does not contain valid private key: /ELK/logstash/SSL/p8key.pem}
```

is because `ssl_key_passphrase => "password"` was not set in the logstash input.

And this error:

```
ERROR org.logstash.beats.BeatsHandler - Exception: not an SSL/TLS record
```

is because non-SSL/TLS traffic was attempting to go through the SSL/TLS port. In this case, the culprit was filebeat.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/security-troubleshooting.html

Comment: @Akodoleyasu
Were you able to rectify this error:
`[INFO ][org.logstash.beats.BeatsHandler] Exception: not an SSL/TLS record`
`[INFO ][org.logstash.beats.BeatsHandler] Exception: Connection reset by peer`
Here's my metribeat.yml file in the next comment. Thanks for the help!

Comment: #----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["elkstack.mydomain.com:5044"]

  ssl.enabled: true
  # Optional SSL. By default is off.
  # List of root certificates for HTTPS server verifications
  ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/ca/ca.crt"]

  # Certificate for SSL client authentication
  ssl.certificate: "/etc/pki/elkstack.mydomain.com/elkstack.mydomain.com.crt"

  # Client Certificate Key
  ssl.key: "/etc/pki/elkstack.mydomain.com/elkstack.mydomain.com.key"

Comment: Thanks for all the help in advance!

Comment: I created a certificate using `certgen` with a passphrase set. But that creates a passphrase for the CA cert. Anyhow that did not work. Can you please help me with this error?