# How to use confluent-kafka with the key store file

Tags: c#, ssl, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, truststore

When I use the Key store file, add property

```
ssl.keystore.location
ssl.keystore.password
ssl.key.password
ssl.truststore.location
ssl.truststore.password
```

in the config, it throws this error:

> Can not find the property ssl.truststore.location"

How can I use librdkafka with key store file? It troubles me, does any one know how to use confluent-kafka with the key store file?

confluent-kafka: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/

Follow the CONFIGURATION.md: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md

I can not find the property in the CONFIGURATION.md

Answer (score 7):

`ssl.keystore.*` and `ssl.truststore.*` are Java client properties,  which make use of Java's JAAS framework and Java-specific trust/keystores.

librdkafka (and its sibling clients) makes use of OpenSSL which uses the PEM and cert file formats.

See this guide how to set it up:
https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/Using-SSL-with-librdkafka

And this SO question explains how to convert keystores to OpenSSL file types:
[Converting a Java Keystore into PEM Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652916/converting-a-java-keystore-into-pem-format)