# keytool error: java.io.IOException: DER input, Integer tag error

Tags: openssl, keytool

I'm trying to convert a private key in a Java Keystore into PEM Format. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652916/converting-a-java-keystore-into-pem-format) explains that the first step is to convert the keystore into PKCS12 format using the `keytool` command.

However, I get the following error:

```
$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore client.keystore.jks -destkeystore client1.p12 -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -srcalias client1 -destalias client1
...
keytool error: java.io.IOException: DER input, Integer tag error
```

Searching for this error online tells me that this has to do with encryption. I know the source keystore is encrypted, but supplying the passwords in the command gives the exact same error. How can I export the private key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be the *destination* keystore, not the source one. The file `client1.p12` already existed but it was in an incompatible format.

The solution was to remove the file `client1.p12` and run the `keytool` command again.