# Does librdkafka and confluent-kafka-go supports JKS based SSL Configuration?

Tags: go, ssl, librdkafka, confluent-kafka-go

Can we configure librdkafka and confluet-kafka-go to use jks files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, JKS is a Java-specific format.
See [Converting a Java Keystore into PEM Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652916/converting-a-java-keystore-into-pem-format) for how to extract certificates in PEM format from a JKS.